# How to eliminate CR from backticks in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Command line utilities in Windows add CRLF as new line symbol in an output.
Does anybody know how to eliminate CR from backticks while running Windows command line utility?

For example:

```
echo "Windows"
TEST=`cmd /c "echo Win"`
echo " ${TEST} " | od -t x1
echo "CYGWIN"
TEST=`echo Win`
echo " ${TEST} " | od -t x1
```

Output:

```
Windows
0000000 20 57 69 6e 0d 20 0a
0000007
CYGWIN
0000000 20 57 69 6e 20 0a
0000006
```

As you can see, backticks of echo from Windows outputs additional CR symbol

Comment: It seems Cygwin must remove CRLF symbols from backtick results, but remove only LF symbol. It gets different results on Windows and Linux. Result on Windows has additional CR symbol and for example string comparision, which is working in Linux, fails in Windows. So I'd expect there is some option in Cygwin which may change it or it is a bug in Cygwin.

Comment: In the (hopefully rare) cases, where you need to run such programs, you could pipe the output through `dos2unix` (AFIK not contained in the Cygwin base package, so you need to install it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr`

```
$ TEST="`cmd /c "echo Win"`"

$ echo  "${TEST}" |od -t x1
0000000 57 69 6e 0d 0a
0000005

$ echo  "${TEST}" | tr -d "\r" |od -t x1
0000000 57 69 6e 0a
0000004
```

Please note that the last "\n" is coming from cygwin echo, not from windows CMD output.

```
$ echo  -n "${TEST}" |od -t x1
0000000 57 69 6e 0d
0000004
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `d2u` (also called `dos2unix`) cygwin command to convert line endings from `CR LF` to `LF`. It can be used to convert a file in-place, to another file, or as a filter in a pipeline. `d2u --help` gives brief help.

The `u2d` (unix2dos) command converts in the opposite direction, `LF` to `CR LF` line endings.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible - run scripts from within mintty.

CR's are added only when script runs in windows CMD terminal.

Described behavior is obviously bug.

Second workaround is to add '\r' to IFS shell variable.